# Oracle 10g - Removing time component

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a text field that is a date, although sometimes it also has the time component. Ex:

```
"23/1/1999"
"25/2/2003 05:18:00"
```

Now, i simply want to query them and order by the date component only. My attempt

```
TO_DATE(
       TO_CHAR(
           TO_DATE(mytextfield  , 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')
       ,'DD-MM-YYYY')
,'MON-YYYY')
```

The above fails on the outer TO_DATE (ORA-01843 invalid month.)

```
TO_CHAR(
    TO_DATE(mytextfield   , 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')
,'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

The above works, but i'm left with a string, not a date.

**-------- Solution using accepted answer**

Just use

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM  TO_DATE(timetable.string_time)  , 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))

EXTRACT(YEAR FROM   TO_DATE(timetable.string_time)  , 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

As stated on the answer, you can swap the order you use it in the ORDER BY and in the SELECT.

Will need a little number formatting on the month, and some concats, but this works very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NLS_DATE_FORMAT` specifies the default date format to use with the `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` functions. Let's change it to get nice output from SQL*Plus:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

First we use `TO_DATE` to convert the textual representation of date into real date type (note that the date format below accepts the shorter text):

```
SELECT TO_DATE('25/2/2003 05:18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
2003-02-25 05:18:00

SELECT TO_DATE('25/2/2003', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
2003-02-25 00:00:00
```

Second - we want to truncate the date to get rid of unnecessary fields ([`TRUNC`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) function):

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('25/2/2003 05:18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) FROM DUAL;
2003-02-25 00:00:00

SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('25/2/2003 05:18:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MONTH') FROM DUAL;
2003-02-01 00:00:00
```

Now you can use this in `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` provided that you want the ordering based on year/month/day (and so on).

If you want to do some exotic sorting (for grouping you don't care: `{year,month}` isn't any different from `{month, year}`)- e.g. month/year, then I think you need to compose the individual fields and use the following:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '1998-03-07') FROM DUAL;
3

SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '1998-03-07') FROM DUAL;
1998
```

Comment: But hot to change the date, after TRUNC, to a MON-YYYY format? I can't manage to do it.

Comment: But why do you want to do that? To create another VARCHAR2 string and store it somewhere in exactly that format? The display format depends on your locale settings! If you want to store it somewhere as VARCHAR2 then TO_CHAR with the correct format.

Comment: This date column will be used to group by later on, that is why. The user may want to do it by month, year, or day. And the column has to be textual, for it is generic.

Comment: Have a look at EXTRACT() function

Comment: @WoF_Angel: Your requirements seem contradictory. In your question, you complained that "The above works, but i'm left with a string, not a date"; now you're complaining that you want a string in the format `MON-YYYY` rather than a date. What am I missing?

Comment: I think all the tools are on the table. Now it's up to WoF_Angel to use them (and tell us what was the thing he had in mind).

Comment: @WoF_Angel: Ignoring some unclear aspects of your question, you could still GROUP BY the field returned by TRUNC with appropriate parameter (year, month, day, ...).

Comment: I want a date at the format MON-YYYY, going from a string of the format '20-03-1980' or '23-04-1987 05:02:00'.

Comment: Date has no format - it is an **internal** representation of date. If for example, you´d like SQL*Plus to **display** dates in a specific format, then `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MON-YYYY';` is your friend. But it still will be a date (with day and time that are not **displayed**)

Comment: Using ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MON-YYYY'; does not work, since i have to set the format on the TO_DATE function, it just gets ignored. And not doing so will just throw me an invalid month error.